# What is this succulent with pointy leaves that seeds constantly fall from?

Tags: identification, succulents

I'm trying to identify this succulent I got from a friend. It spreads in two ways:
- Sometimes a stalk will tip to the side, and then sprout roots downward to creep along. One of the photos below documents this.
- More often, though, seeds form along the edge of the leaf, drop to the ground, and start new plants.

From my findings so far, the best I can figure is that it's some sort of kalanchoe - but I'm not entirely sure about that.

Other info:
- Leaf parings alternate: one pair will be front and back, and the next will be left and right
- the leaf edges are serrated, and bear a thin red line along them
- I'm growing it inside, in a pot. It loves direct sunlight most of the day, and is thriving near windows
- I water it weekly, allowing it to completely dry between waterings. It seems quite happy with this arrangement.

[image: the whole plant]
[image: leaf close up]
[image: the dropping and rooting behavior]

Comment: careful w/ your pets around that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description of 'seeds' falling from the edges of the leaves, and the plant's general appearance, its likely Kalanchoe daigremontiana (now called Bryophyllum daigremontianum), image here

http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/166243/

Common names include Mother of Thousands, Mother of Hundreds, Mexican Hat plant. Care information here

http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/kalanchoe/growing-mother-of-thousands.htm