# What is this succulent with narrow stems and small growths along the edges of the leaves?

Tags: identification, succulents

This succulent has narrow stems, and small growths along the edges of the leaves.

Can anybody tell me what succulent it is?

[image]

Comment: Is that a fireplace at the end of this swimming pool?  What an extravagance!! Yummy!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this succulent with pointy leaves that seeds constantly fall from?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24889/what-is-this-succulent-with-pointy-leaves-that-seeds-constantly-fall-from)

Comment: I agree with the duplicate, but the pictures are very different!

Comment: Looking more closely at both questions makes me wonder if they're the same variety of Kalanchoe. Does anybody else want to weigh in, like @Brenn? Even if they are, this plant looks older and shows the plantlets, which are one of the most important, and interesting, identifying features. I think this should stay open and the other "related."

Comment: I hope nobody thinks I prefer my own answer. The question asked only for identification, not care instructions. The rest was just some things I thought might be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 5):

This is Kalanchoe daigremontiana tubifolia (Mother of Thousands) plant. You have the photograph of a beautiful specimen.

Answer (score 3):

As @Srihari Yamanoor said, this appears to be a [Kalanchoe daigremontiana,](http://www.drought-smart-plants.com/kalanchoe-daigremontiana.html) a succulent in the [Crassulaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassulaceae) family.

One thing that makes it unique among all succulents is that it has little "plantlets" along the leaves. They are exact duplicates of the original plant. As they grow, they drop off into the soil and root themselves. You  can also pop them off and root them separately if you'd like. This process is part of where it got the nickname "Mother of Thousands." Some even call it "Mother of Millions."

It grows up to 2-1/2 ft (75 cm) tall.

it originated in Madagascar, so it likes the heat. In fact, it will tolerate even extreme heat, but frost will kill it quickly. It's hardy in zones 9-11, so in most areas it grows better as a houseplant. Indoors it prefers average room temperatures of 60-75°F/16-24°C. Keep it in bright to full sun outdoors, or a sunny window inside. You can also alternate between outside and inside as the weather changes.

When potted, it grows best in soil made for cactus and other succulents. Water it thoroughly, and let the top 2 inches or so dry out before watering again. In the winter, cut back on watering, but never let the soil completely dry out.

It's important to note that this is a very poisonous plant when ingested. All parts are poisonous, to both pets and children.

For more information:
[Guide to Houseplants](http://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/mother-of-thousands.html)
[Drought Smart Plants](http://www.drought-smart-plants.com/kalanchoe-daigremontiana.html0)

The flowers are unusual too,

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Source for all pictures.](http://hubpages.com/living/Flowering-Mother-of-Thousands-Plants)

Comment: Keep this plant if this is yours away from that pool.  The vaporizing chlorine is a killer for sensitive plants.  And the knowledge this plant itself is toxic to kiddies and pets and intoxicated adults is SUPER!